# "But a core of his practice even more so is observation and writing."

Tags: reference

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> Even as a teenager, Vitalik Buterin proved to be a pithy writer, able
> to articulate complex ideas about cryptocurrency and its underlying
> technology in clear prose. At 18, he co-founded Bitcoin Magazine and
> became its lead writer, earning a following both in Toronto and
> abroad. “A lot of people think of him as a typical techie engineer,”
> says Nathan Schneider, a media-studies professor at the University of
> Colorado, Boulder, who first interviewed Buterin in 2014. “But a core
> of his practice **even more so** is observation and writing—and that
> helped him see a cohesive vision that others weren’t seeing yet.”

From [what I read on the internet](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-use-of-even-more-so.3241056/#:%7E:text=The%20phrase%20%22even%20more%20so,the%20same%20as%20%22especially%22.), 'even more so' is, as a single chunk, much the same as "especially", which makes total sense to me in the above context.

But if I consider the phrase from the point of view that 'so' in 'even more so' is an adjective [*used to replace a preceding adjective*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so) and [the definition of 'more so'](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/more_so) is '*of the same kind to a greater degree*.', I wonder what it is that 'so' refers to in the above context.

My sense is that it refers to 'being a core of his practice'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't separate the "so."

The idiom is **[(all) the more so](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28all%29%20the%20more%20so)**. You use it most often to indicate that something applies more to one thing than another. For example:

> He's a talented drummer, all the more so because he only has one arm.

**Even** is just a variation that adds emphasis:

> He's a talented drummer, even more so because he only has one arm.

Comment: Thank you very much.